# Firestore : why using serverTimestamp gives different results?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a hard time understanding serverTimestamp in firestore.

When I save a document in database in a firebase function using `Fieldvalue.serverTimestamp()` or in a javascript client code using `serverTimestamp()` it sometimes doesn't save the same thing in the database.

See screenshots below :

[image]

Sometime I get an object with `{nanoseconds: xxx, seconds: xxx}` and sometimes I get a timestamp formatted date...

The problem is when I try to query my orders using `query(collectionRefOrders, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'), limit(10))`.
The orders with the object appears before the others ones even if they are created after...

Any clue why this happens ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :

Here is the code I use to add documents in the my firebase function (it is a request function I call in a website) :

```
const { getFirestore, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

const firebaseDB = getFirestore();

exports.createOrderFromTunnel = functions.region('europe-west3')
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 10,
    memory: "4GB",
  })
  .https
  .onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        const { apiKey } = req.body;

        const project = await getProjectFromApiKey(apiKey);

        if (!project) {
          return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Unauthorized: invalid or missing api key'
          });
        }

        const contactData = {
          address: {},
          createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        };

        const orderData = {
          accounting: {
            totalHT: 0,
            totalTTC: 0,
            totalTVA: 0,
          },
          createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          status: 'NEW',
        };

        const refProject = firebaseDB
          .collection('projects')
          .doc(project.id);
        const colOrder = firebaseDB.collection(`projects/${project.id}/orders`)
        const refOrder = colOrder.doc();
        const colContact = firebaseDB.collection(`projects/${project.id}/contacts`)
        const refContact = colContact.doc();

        await firebaseDB.runTransaction(async transaction => {
          const snapProject = await transaction.get(refProject);

          const dataProject = snapProject.data();
          const sequenceContact = dataProject.sequenceContact;
          const sequenceOrder = dataProject.sequenceOrder;

          contactData.sequence = sequenceContact;
          orderData.sequenceNumber = sequenceOrder;

          await transaction.set(refContact, contactData);

          orderData.customer.id = refContact.id;
          orderData.customer.sequence = sequenceContact;

          await transaction.set(refOrder, orderData);
          await transaction.update(refProject, {
            sequenceContact: sequenceContact + 1,
            sequenceOrder: sequenceOrder + 1,
            totalContacts: dataProject.totalContacts + 1,
            totalOrders: dataProject.totalOrders + 1,
          });
          return refOrder.id;
        });

        return res.json({
          success: true
        });
      } catch (err) {
        functions.logger.error(err);

        return res.json({
          success: false,
          err
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Here is the code I use to add documents in my client code (it is a web app in javascript) :

```
const createOrder = async (projectId) => {
  try {
    const orderData = {
      accounting: {
        totalHT: 0,
        totalTTC: 0,
        totalTVA: 0,
      },
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      status: 'NEW',
      surface: 0,
    };

    const refProject = doc(firebaseDB, 'projects', projectId);
    const colOrder = collection(firebaseDB, `projects/${projectId}/orders`)
    const refOrder = doc(colOrder);

    return await runTransaction(firebaseDB, async (transaction) => {
      const snapProject = await transaction.get(refProject);
      if (!snapProject.exists()) {
        throw "Document does not exist!";
      }

      const dataProject = snapProject.data();
      const sequence = dataProject.sequenceOrder;
      orderData.sequenceNumber = sequence;

      transaction.set(refOrder, orderData);
      transaction.update(refProject, { sequenceOrder: sequence + 1, totalOrders: dataProject.totalOrders + 1 });
      return refOrder.id;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to add those timestamps in documents from both clients?

Comment: Please provide [complete minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that we can use the reproduce the behavior.  You are certainly doing something wrong, but we can't see what it is.

Comment: Thank you for you replies, I edited my question and added both piece of code I use. Let me know if you need further details. Thank you

Comment: Given all this code, what steps do you take to reproduce the problem?  Saying "sometimes" is not very helpful - it's better to state exactly what causes the problem as you observe it.

Comment: I don't know... it happens randomly. I can't figure out specific course of events that produce it. Sometimes it saves an object in the createdAt field, and sometimes not. I was wondering if there is some rule that will tell me when it will save as an object with seconds and nanoseconds props and when it will save just a timestamp.